# Permutation of strings

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to try and program a bruteforce attack using all the letters in the alphabet and numbers from 0-9.

I have used string permutation which allows me to generate all combinations possible from characters in a string. e.g abc would give me abc, acb, bca.. etc. I have a problem though as it displays a line of 36 characters. I am able to resize the strings so it outputs in 5, 10 and 15 character lines, but some of my string characters (mainly starting from abcde...etc) are missing. I want it to generate all the characters and numbers in the string, not just a chunk of them so when it generates the combinations on the console window it will use every character in the string. Does anyone know why it only outputs a chunk of characters rather than all of them? Especially the length 5 string, which only prints out numbers, 10 printing z and numbers and 15 printing from u-z and numbers.
Here is what comes up on the console window:

```
class Attack
{
public:
    string username;
    string password;
    int x;
    string wordonlist;
    string combinations;
};
    void BruteforceAtt()
    {
        Attack bruteforce;

        bruteforce.combinations = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789";

        cout<<"BruteForce Attack is a go..."<<endl;
        cout<<"Searching..."<<endl;
        cout<<""<<endl;

        {
            cout<<bruteforce.combinations.substr(bruteforce.combinations.length() - 5)<<endl;
            cout<<bruteforce.combinations.substr(bruteforce.combinations.length() - 10)<<endl;
            cout<<bruteforce.combinations.substr(bruteforce.combinations.length() - 15)<<endl;

        } while (next_permutation(bruteforce.combinations.begin(), bruteforce.combinations.end()));

        system("Pause");
    };
```

Comment: Please show the output you got and what you expected. The way you phrased it sounds confusing. And show the implementation of `next_permutation()` as well as the `Attack` class.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves `next_permutation` is a standard function from `algorithm` header

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Ah, nice to know. I was not aware of that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`next_combination` expects the input to be sorted in order to iterate over all permutations and your input is not sorted - `1` is before `a` in terms of ASCII code. Also note that even if you fix your code you will have to perform `36!` steps which is enormous(`371993326789901217467999448150835200000000`) - even on the fastest computer up to date this will take more than the universe is supposed to live **by far**.

Comment: _"this will take more than the universe is supposed to live by far."_ - Unless you run it on a bunch of Colecovisions.